# Libgdx - box2d polygonshape doesn't fit its sprite

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite, box2d, shapes

I have a body with a polygonshape created using .setasbox but when I run my game the box is a bit bigger than my sprite.
I know setasbox uses half height and half width, I used my scaling constant to convert meters to pixels and I know the sprite has the origin of the axis on the bottom left as well. Despite of that I still have a box with a width a bit larger than the sprite and this gap is the same however I change the size of the box...

This is the code I use to create my box (160 is the constant to scale meters to pixels):

```java
 public Block(World w, float halfWidth, float halfHeight, Vector2 position, Texture tex){
    world = w;

    bodyd = new BodyDef();
    bodyd.type = BodyDef.BodyType.KinematicBody;
    bodyd.gravityScale = 0;
    shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    fixtured = new FixtureDef();
    fixtured.shape = shape;
    fixtured.density = DENS;
    fixtured.friction = FRIC;
    fixtured.restitution = REST;


    bodyd.position.set(new Vector2(position.x, position.y));
    body = world.createBody(bodyd);
    fixture = body.createFixture(fixtured);
    body.setUserData(this);


    texture = tex;
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    sprite.setSize(halfWidth * 2 * 160, halfHeight*2*160);
    sprite.setPosition((body.getPosition().x - halfWidth) * 160, (body.getPosition().y - halfHeight) * 160);
}
```

Comment: please attach screenshot and code of creating the box - what are dimensions of your sprite?

Comment: I just attached my code

Answer (score 0):

can you try using Box2DSprite? its very easy..

https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils/wiki/net.dermetfan.gdx.graphics.g2d.Box2DSprite

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=29843.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code

did you consider that the size that you put for your sprite is the size of the full sprite not the size of the block inside your sprite

I think this is why your brick sprite is smaller than your brick physic :

[image]

unless the your brick has the full size of the sprite then may be the problem is related to something else

hope that was helpful !